# ClassCastException : cant be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java

I know this has been asked a lot in stackoverflow but I could not find answers that work to my problem.

In the following code below, I cant print out each item in `ArrayList<Integer>` because it says that `"Edge cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"`.

I have tried to print each item using `for(Integer item :p1)` and also `for (int item: p1)` but both did not work.

I think maybe the problem is because of the `toString()` method in Edge class but if i do not use `toString()` I cant get the real key number (it will be printed as `Edge@28a418fc` or something like this)

Thanks for helping before

**Main class**

```
public class Ranker7 {

    static Graph g;
    static Node n;
    static Edge e;
    static HashMap<Integer, Node> nodeMap; 
    int id;
    static double weight;
    static int year;
    static int type;

    Ranker7() {
            g = new Graph();
            nodeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();
            n = new Node(id,year,type,weight);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        /**Rule Mining**/
        Ranker7 Ranker = new Ranker7();
        Connection connect = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = null;
        ResultSet resultSet2 = null;
        HashMap nodeMap =  new HashMap();  

        System.out.println("Processing...");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/arnetminer?"+"user=root&password=1234");
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("Select fr,t,ty from subedge");

        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        int i=0;

        while(resultSet.next()) {
           g.addEdgeForIndexing(resultSet.getInt(1),resultSet.getInt(2),resultSet.getInt(3));         
           i++;             
           System.out.println( "edges added to G = "+i);
        }       

        System.out.println("Loaded " + g.nodeCount() + " nodes.");

        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("Select node,year,type from subnode2");
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        int h=0;
        while(resultSet.next()) {
               Node n = new Node(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getInt(2),resultSet.getInt(3),weight);
               int key1=resultSet.getInt(1);
               nodeMap.put(key1,n);
               h++;             
        }

        System.out.println(nodeMap);
        System.out.println(nodeMap.size());

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many authors do you want to enter?");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int[] authorNames = new int[num];
        for(int a = 0; a < authorNames.length; a++){
            System.out.println("Enter author name:");
            authorNames[a] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Year : ");
        int inputYear3 = sc.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> p1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        /**Get the papers written by input author A-P**/    
        for(int b=0; b< authorNames.length;b++){
            int AuthorID1 = authorNames[b];
            p1 = g.getOutEdgesToP(AuthorID1);
        }

        for(int item : p1){ //the error of classcastexception is here
            System.out.println(item); 
        }

    }
}
```

**Edge class**

```
public class Edge {


    int from;
    int to;
    int type;
    private static int counter = 0;
    public Edge(int from, int to, int type) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.type = type;
    //  System.out.println("edges added from " + from + " to " +  to + " with type "+ type);
    }

    public String toString(){
        String repr = Integer.toString(to);
        return repr;
    }
    public int getfrom(){
        return from;
    }

    public int getto(){
        return to;
    }

    public int getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public void setfrom(int from){
        this.from = from;
    }

    public void setto(int to){
        this.to = to;
    }

    public void setType(int type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

**Graph class**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {

    private HashSet<Integer>  nodeIDs;   
    public HashMap<Integer, String> nodeIDsWithTN;
    public HashMap<Integer, String> TNMap;  
    private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>  edges;
    private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>  reverse;
    private int numNodes;
    private int numEdges;
    private int numReverse;

    public Graph() {
        edges = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        reverse = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        nodeIDs = new HashSet<Integer>();
        nodeIDsWithTN = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        TNMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        new HashSet();
    }

    public void addEdgeForIndexing(int from, int to, int T) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {   

            Edge e = new Edge(from,to,T);
            nodeIDs.add(e.from);
            nodeIDs.add(e.to);

            ArrayList tmp = null;
            if (edges.containsKey(e.from))
              tmp = (ArrayList) edges.get(e.from);
            else {
              tmp = new ArrayList();
              edges.put(e.from,tmp);
            }
            tmp.add(e);

            ArrayList tmp2 = null;
            if (reverse.containsKey(e.to))
              tmp2 = (ArrayList) reverse.get(e.to);
            else {
              tmp2 = new ArrayList();
              reverse.put(e.to,tmp2);
            }
            tmp2.add(e);

    }

    public int nodeCount() {
        if(nodeIDs.size() > 0) 
            return nodeIDs.size();
            // else return numNodes;
        return numEdges;
    }

    public int countInEdges(Integer key) {
        if (!reverse.containsKey(key)) return 0;
            return ((ArrayList<?>) reverse.get(key)).size();
    }

    public int countOutEdges(Integer key) {
        if (!edges.containsKey(key)) return 0;
            return ((ArrayList<?>) edges.get(key)).size();
    }
/**
    public ArrayList<String> getInEdgesFromPtoA(String id) {
        if (!reverse.containsKey(id)) return null;  
            ArrayList<String> a = reverse.get(id);
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int j=0;j<a.size();j++){
                      if(a.get(j).startsWith("A")){
                          result.add(a.get(j));                           
                      }
                 }
        return result;
    }
**/

      public ArrayList<Integer> getOutEdges(Integer key) {
            if (!edges.containsKey(key)) 
                return null;

            ArrayList<Integer> value = edges.get(key);
            return value;
      }


      public ArrayList<Integer> getOutEdgesToP(int id) {
            if (!edges.containsKey(id)) {
                return null;
            }

            ArrayList<Integer> a = edges.get(id);           
            System.out.println ("Arraylist a: " + a); //if i print using this its okay. but i cant get each item in this ArrayList like below
            for(int item : a){ //the error of classcastexception is here
                System.out.println(item);
            }

            return a;
     }

    public Iterator<Integer> nodeIteratorInitial() {
        return nodeIDs.iterator();
    }
}
```

**Node class**

```
public class Node {

      int id;
      double weight;
      int year;
      int type;
      private static int counter = 0;

      public Node(int id,int year,int type,double weight) {
          this.id = id;
          this.year=year;
          this.weight = weight;
          this.type = type;
     }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          // here you can create your own representation of the object
          String repr = "id:" + id + ", year:" + year + ", weight:" + weight + ", node type:" + type;
          return repr;
          }

    public double getWeight(){
            return weight;
      }

      public int getid() {
           return id;
      }

      public int getType() {
           return type;
      }

      public int getYear() {
           return year;
      }

      public void setWeight(double weight){
         this.weight=weight;
      }

      public void setid(int id){
          this.id=id;
      }

      public void setType() {
           this.type=type;
      }
}
```

Comment: Did you try ` for(Integer item : p1)` instead of ` for(int item : p1)` ?

Comment: @mtyurt Yes I tried both..

Comment: You're using a lot of raw types... why? (e.g. In Graph#addEdgeForIndexing)

Comment: @Tom I created the program but for addEdgeForIndexing method I actually had reference from somewhere else. I ll try to fix that then thank you.

Comment: @fuschia Raw types are often the source of evil, so you should try to always avoid them. I guess this question is a good example why this can cause problems :).

Comment: Please provide a **minimum** example to reproduce. Try to remove those lines which are not required to see the problem happen. Oh, BTW, then you would probably have found the solution yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>  edges;

// ...later

Edge e = new Edge(from,to,T);

// ...later

else {
    tmp = new ArrayList();
    edges.put(e.from,tmp);
}
tmp.add(e);
```

Ultimately, this is a classic example of [why raw types are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664). You've got an `ArrayList<Integer>` and you put `Edge`s in it.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to tell you how to fix it since I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I created the program but for addEdgeForIndexing method I actually had reference from somewhere else. I ll try to fix that then thank you.

Comment: Double-check the logic, I guess. It could be for example that `edges` should be a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Edge>>`.

Comment: Good catch! @fuschia as Radiodef mentioned, using raw-types is bad practice (and the outcome is exactly this mess you're having now). Use generics with every collection/map and these errors will be caught at compilation time and will be clearer!

Comment: +(2-1) more for *I don't understand what you're trying to do.*

Comment: Thanks all this is actually the problem! When I defined the type for tmp, it now works but i have a logic error in my program now. I ll try to fix that. What important is the ClassCastException problem is solved! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Thomas Just being honest, really.

Answer (score 5):

the error lies here

```
  public void addEdgeForIndexing(int from, int to, int T) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {   

            Edge e = new Edge(from,to,T);
            nodeIDs.add(e.from);
            nodeIDs.add(e.to);

            ArrayList tmp = null;
            if (edges.containsKey(e.from))
              tmp = (ArrayList) edges.get(e.from);
            else {
              tmp = new ArrayList();
              edges.put(e.from,tmp);
            }
            tmp.add(e);//adding an edge to tmp
```

later in the code you get the ArrayList out of the Map as ArrayList but it an ArrayList containing Edge
try to change

```
tmp = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

you should get a compilation error when adding an Edge to it

Comment: Thanks all this is actually the problem! When I defined the type for tmp, it now works but i have a logic error in my program now. I ll try to fix that. What important is the ClassCastException problem is solved! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You declare:

```
int from;
int to;
int type;
```

and you should declare them as `Integer`s instead:

```
Integer from;
Integer to;
Integer type;
```

because later on you're doing:

```
this.from = new Integer(from);
```

etc.

A better option would be to change the assignment to:

```
this.from = from;
```

which would also solve this error since you would be assigning an `int` to an `int`. Is there a purpose you're using `new Integer()` ? because if not - I would suggest removing it - it's slower (performance-wise) comparing to the primitive `int`.

Bottom line: stay consistent and either use `int` throughout the code, or `Integer` - try not to mix them unless it's really required.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I changed everything to int since I need a better performance. also, i do not really have a reason why I used new Integer(). But the problem of ClassCastException still could not be solved. Thanks but I think I might have missed something else also.

Comment: @fuschia please post the code of class `Node` as well

Answer (score 1):

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> getOutEdgesToP(int id) {
if (!edges.containsKey(id)) {
    return null;
}
System.out.println(edges.get(id));
ArrayList<Integer> a = edges.get(id);
System.out.println("Arraylist a: " + a); // if i print using this its
                     // okay. but i cant get each
                     // item in this ArrayList like
                     // below
for (Object item : a) { // the error of classcastexception is here
    System.out.println(item);
}

return a;
}
```

This should work. I don't have a lot of time to search for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you! But i actually need it to be int so that the performance is better because i need to loop through a lot of items there.