# Hashmap Long to Integer ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, casting, hashmap

The following is my hashmap.

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> details;
details = new HashMap<>();
details.put("coins", 0);
details.put("score", 0);
details.put("wins", 0);
```

The following is my get coins method

```
public int getCoinCount() {
    if(details == null)
        return 0;

    return  details.get("coins").intValue();
}
```

Now when I run this I get a `ClassCastException`. The following is the code that is calling it.

```
int coins =  MyClass.getInstance().getCoinCount();
```

It says I can't cast a long to an integer! THERE WAS NEVER A MENTION TO A LONG TYPE! WHAT IS GOING ON?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at game.drew.com.respy.User.User.getCoinCount(RespyUser.java:78)
at game.drew.com.game.Gameplay.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:226)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
```

Comment: Can you give us the full stacktrace please?

Comment: @HuskyHuskie just added stacktrace

Comment: getCoinCount is a method in MyClass. It returns an int. The method definition is above.

Comment: Could you show the method of `game.drew.com.game.Gameplay.ProfileFragment#onCreateView`? I think the `int coins = MyClass.getInstance().getCoinCount()` is OK, but then the int value is passed in ProfileFragment, and it raised an exception there.

Comment: @Drew Furniss refer to this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/29666879/4606122

Comment: Cannot reproduce from this code. You must have some other code somewhere that changes the value and uses a `long` or `Long` to do so.

Comment: @MincongHuang but why would the error be taking me to the where it calls getCoinCount?

Comment: Nope. It seems like the HashMap value is returning a Long. But why would it if it is a <String, Integer> map? I don't use a long type anywhere in my project. @EJP

Answer (score -2):

I was hoping your stacktrace would give me more to go off of, unfortunately I'm about as puzzled as you are. This isn't a true fix to your problem, but since you are putting the values into the `HashMap` as as `Integer` it might be best to change `getCoinCount` to also return an `Integer` and set `coins` to be an `Integer` as well.

In the past when I get a primitive value from an `Integer` I usually end up retrieving it as a `long` too.